# Should I rush B? How?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Rushing B on Dust II is a very well-known strategy. It is a subject to many jokes and memes.
I have asked some CS:GO players why is it that well-known, they have said "*because it is so effective*".

However, I have found some claims that this strategy is actually ineffective and only used by bad players. My B rushes were also by far not always successful. Which is true?

When, if ever, should I rush B? How should I execute this strategy properly?

Comment: I guess you're talking about the (in)famous B rush on dust2? There are a lot of other maps with a B site. :)

Comment: @dly True! I have clarified that

Comment: Too broad? Seriously?

Comment: The people who voted to close this at too broad have obviously never played CSGO before. Rushing B is a clear and obvious strategy with hundreds of thousands of hours going into the meta game competitively. This is very much answerable, not opinion based and can be broken down into a great answer.

Answer (score 19):

A B rush needs to be well timed and executed. Also you need some smokes and flashes. If you don't have them you're doomed anyway. This strategy is just as effective as the players doing it are skilled. Stupid players will do it in a stupid way and likely fail. Good players are able to do it properly.

A successful B rush requires some aim and quick thinking. Since it's a rush people standing still will probably fail the whole thing. And a rush is obviously not over when you're on the site.

1. Smoke the entrance to the tunnel and the box on the site, so if someone hides there they're blind.
2. Optionally (but recommended) you can smoke the doors to disable any snipers lurking around in the middle.
3. Throw at least 2 flashes: one on the site and one over the wall to the middle.
4. Get in and spread out: check the camping spots first (car, crates,...). Be clear who goes where before you're on the site. The CTs aren't blind forever.
5. Be prepared for the retake. A lot of B rushes fail, because people are not prepared and people running off chasing the CTs.

   - Keep some grenades to counter theirs.
   - If you're getting flashed, throw one back.
   - Avoid spots close to the wall or in the line of sight to the CT spawn. You'll likely get sniped.
   - Watch the time. It takes 13 seconds to get to B from A long and 8 seconds to get there from short. You can easily step on their brakes when they eat your flash right when they walk around the corner.
   - Don't get involved in duels. If you see someone, shoot and back off. Just guard the bomb.
   - Guard the tunnels, if you don't have someone left behind guarding the middle.
6. Boom. You win.

If you want to practice B rushes, try it in eco rounds. If you're on eco you still need those grenades. If they are, be prepared for unusual tactics.

PS: If you do it with four people it can be useful, too. Someone distracting the guys on A and then covering your back from the middle can be very helpful. The CTs will have to deal with that guy as well as trying to get on B, which can be big bonus for you... The tunnel is covered and maybe one or two extra kills secure the round for you even before they get close.

Comment: Could you please include a scheme of where exactly should we land our grenades? I would accept the answer then. Would also like to know which weapons are good for the rush and which are bad.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I'll try when I'm back on the right PC (probably on Sunday)

Answer (score 5):

Don't have the rep to comment so I'll just leave this as an addendum to dly's comment.
Another effective smoke that I have found works well is one that bounces off the left tunnel wall and lands between the tunnel entrance and door/stack. Blocks off all of the right side to let you clear close corners and platform before flashing through to deal with door, window etc.

Secondly just to clarify dly's point 3, get in means don't stop to take fights, especially in tunnel entrance where you'll block all your teammates and be an easy spray down. In a B rush you'll typically have pistols or SMGs so your moving accuracy should be fairly decent, use that to spread out while clearing the site. One or two people will die, just make sure you use that time to get up close and personal with the on site CTs.

Lastly be careful with your nade usage when you're not with a well communicating team. Because of the narrow entrance it can be difficult to get out effective flashes without blinding your entire team and other nades can be blocked by people randomly stopping.

Comment: You can also directly suggest an edit @dly 's answer, no matter how small amount of rep you have. :) You need to either edit your answer to stand on its own, as if it was the only answer to the question, or move the info to dly's answer.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: Don't forget to yell: Сука Блять!

Most of it is already covered, I just want to add this:

"Hug" the right side of the tunnel while moving/entering. This gives you a better angle (CTs which are late on B can never shoot into the tunnel). The downside: You're standing in one line, sometimes you'll all get shot at once if the timing is bad).

My friends and I usually do it like this:
First player throws a flash to the left side of the tunnel (it bounces off and pops on site). We all turn around while moving so we dont get flashed. Second Player usually throws a smoke the same way to block the sniper position.

Comment: +1 for Сука Блять also do some Gopnik squats during freeze time.

Comment: [A related video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8I8N4Me5r1I)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, assuming that you are playing in "lower" ranks you should really try to not overthink a b-rush. The first and most important thing is that all teammates take part in the rush and dont stop halfway. You will most likely lose 1-2 People to get on the site. If you can refrag them you are in prime position to take the round since its hard to retake B 3 vs 3.

Having said that there are a number of things you can do to make it easier for your team.

1. Try to use 1-2 Flashbangs that do not blind your teammates. You need to practice this but its absolutely possible to bounce them off the left wall in a way that you do not get blind at all.
2. Smoke the B-Doors as soon as possible.
3. Plant the bomb in the open so it can be seen from tunnels.
4. Keep the doors smoked as long as possible (while the doors are smoked its close to impossible to retake from mid).
5. Keep one player close to the window in order to kill everyone trying to push through.
6. One player should play 'car' (the spot) in order to watch the door smoke and help if there is a lot of pressure at window.
7. Try to keep tunnel control if possible to cut off flanks and exit once the time gets low. As long as you are up in numbers one player can stay in the tunnel and hold the stairs angle.

One last thing: If you can avoid it try to not peak mid at all costs. Peaking mid from B is a very CT-sided fight that you dont need to take once the bomb is down.

Comment: Can you please add a scheme of how should I use my nades (all of them)? What does "play a car" mean? How exactly should I keep tunnel control?

Comment: How do you all your nades depends on your team. If you are the only one throwing grenades a flash to entry and the fast door smoke are by far the most important nades you can throw. Every nade you have left can be used to delay any retake attempt (flash over the wall, burn the window, smoke the door). Holding tunnel can be achieved by just aiming at the stairs.

Answer (score 1):

One effective way of rush b is through mid doors, a flash to blind the snipers near the car and a smoke towards the crates that blocks the CT spawn and A site, requires atleast two players to rush B from there. Also it requires pinning down the CT's from tunnel and distracting them from the B doors.

Answer (score -5):

You should rush B when you're full team is friends and being in something like a skype(good Communication with other players) and having a Desert-Eagle and good aim.

Comment: You should consider expanding your answer (With the edit button) to better explain why communication is important to rushing B, and why a Desert eagle is a required weapon.

Comment: This seems like poor advice...  The game already has voice communication; you don't need skype.  The desert eagle isn't really great for rushing.  You also don't explain how having friends helps.